# Time data does not match format - List of Strings to Date

Tags: python, list, date, time, python-datetime

I have a list of dates (in string format):

```
Mon Jun 15 16:52:18 2020,Mon Jun 15 16:52:35 2020,Mon Jun 15 16:52:29 2020,Mon Jun 15 18:25:30 2020,Mon Jun 15 18:25:14 2020,Mon Jun 15 18:25:50 2020,Mon Jun 15 18:24:47 2020,Mon Jun 15 18:26:04 2020,Sun Jun 14 23:00:53 2020,Sun Jun 14 23:00:24 2020,Sun Jun 14 02:30:00 2020,Sun Jun 14 01:31:11 2020,Wed Jun 17 03:44:40 2020,Sun Jun 14 02:30:00 2020,Sun Jun 14 23:30:30 2020,Sun Jun 14 01:02:47 2020,Sun Jun 14 23:00:00 2020,Sun Jun 14 02:30:00 2020,Sun Jun 14 01:30:01 2020,Sun Jun 14 04:00:00 2020,Sun Jun 14 00:00:00 2020,Sun Jun 14 23:35:37 2020,Sun Jun 14 01:00:36 2020,Sun Jun 14 01:00:43 2020,Sun Jun 14 03:00:00 2020,Sun Jun 14 05:31:01 2020,Wed Jun 17 00:00:00 2020,Sun Jun 14 04:30:29 2020,Sun Jun 14 04:30:18 2020,Sun Jun 14 23:30:42 2020,Mon Jun 15 11:30:51 2020,Sat Jun 13 04:46:41 2020,Sat Jun 13 23:23:19 2020,Sun Jun 14 03:35:44 2020,Sun Jun 14 02:00:17 2020,Sun Jun 14 04:30:02 2020,Sun Jun 14 04:00:00 2020,Sun Jun 14 04:30:02 2020,Sun Jun 14 03:30:26 2020,Mon Jun 15 06:10:04 2020,Sun Jun 14 23:30:00 2020,Sun Jun 14 04:30:23 2020,Tue Jun 16 00:01:22 2020,Sun Jun 14 07:00:31 2020,Sun Jun 14 05:00:25 2020,Sun Jun 14 05:31:08 2020,Sun Jun 14 06:00:57 2020,Sun Jun 14 03:30:26 2020,Sun Jun 14 06:31:21 2020,Sun Jun 14 07:31:15 2020,Sun Jun 14 23:30:54 2020,Sun Jun 14 23:00:34 2020,Sun Jun 14 00:00:16 2020,Sun Jun 14 23:30:00 2020,Sun Jun 14 00:32:45 2020,Sun Jun 14 00:00:00 2020,Sun Jun 14 01:00:00 2020,Sun Jun 14 01:31:22 2020,Sun Jun 14 01:00:36 2020,Sun Jun 14 02:00:31 2020,Sun Jun 14 02:30:00 2020,Sun Jun 14 02:00:00 2020,Sun Jun 14 03:00:00 2020,Sun Jun 14 06:00:00 2020,Sun Jun 14 23:00:43 2020,Sun Jun 14 06:32:22 2020,Sun Jun 14 01:30:42 2020,Sun Jun 14 07:01:51 2020,Sun Jun 14 04:00:37 2020,Sun Jun 14 04:30:00 2020,Sun Jun 14 05:00:00 2020,Sun Jun 14 07:30:00 2020,Sun Jun 14 05:30:02 2020,Sun Jun 14 06:31:57 2020,Sun Jun 14 05:32:13 2020,Sun Jun 14 04:30:55 2020,Sun Jun 14 04:30:33 2020,Sun Jun 14 03:31:01 2020,Sun Jun 14 03:01:37 2020,Sun Jun 14 23:01:20 2020,Sun Jun 14 01:30:37 2020,Sun Jun 14 00:32:58 2020,Sun Jun 14 04:30:33 2020,Sun Jun 14 02:31:21 2020,Sun Jun 14 02:30:00 2020,Sun Jun 14 02:06:32 2020,Sun Jun 14 00:33:23 2020,Sun Jun 14 05:35:57 2020,Sun Jun 14 01:41:34 2020,Sun Jun 14 03:26:45 2020,Sun Jun 14 23:04:23 2020,Mon Jun 15 02:00:00 2020,Mon Jun 15 00:00:00 2020,Mon Jun 15 02:09:36 2020,Mon Jun 15 02:17:56 2020,Mon Jun 15 05:18:49 2020,Sun Jun 14 02:02:17 2020,Sun Jun 14 02:33:29 2020,Sun Jun 14 03:04:07 2020,Sun Jun 14 03:32:27 2020,Sun Jun 14 04:01:12 2020,Sun Jun 14 04:31:56 2020,Mon Jun 01 04:07:32 2020,Mon Jun 01 23:13:54 2020,Wed Jun 17 00:47:52 2020,Wed Jun 17 00:00:01 2020,Mon Jun 15 01:03:49 2020,Mon Jun 15 03:46:08 2020,Mon Jun 15 01:35:47 2020,Mon Jun 08 04:50:16 2020,Wed Jun 10 02:09:00 2020,Mon Jun 15 13:47:52 2020,Mon Jun 15 13:41:07 2020,Sun Jun 14 05:00:53 2020,Sun Jun 14 00:39:21 2020,Sun Jun 14 05:34:17 2020,Sun Jun 14 06:07:53 2020,Sun Jun 14 06:33:38 2020,Mon Jun 15 06:23:03 2020,Thu Jun 11 04:33:07 2020,Thu Apr 23 07:37:15 2020,Mon Jun 15 05:51:41 2020,Tue Jun 16 23:14:37 2020,Thu May 21 06:46:18 2020,Mon Jun 01 04:49:40 2020,Tue Jun 16 09:19:14 2020,Sun Jun 14 07:32:27 2020,Tue Jun 16 01:40:38 2020,Mon Jun 15 07:48:52 2020,Tue Jun 16 02:09:54 2020,Tue Jun 16 23:12:00 2020,Tue Jun 16 03:12:23 2020,Tue May 12 00:56:51 2020,Tue Jun 16 04:10:43 2020,Tue Jun 16 01:10:45 2020,Tue Jun 16 05:08:58 2020,Fri Jun 12 02:32:55 2020,Tue Jun 16 06:15:51 2020,Tue Jun 16 23:24:24 2020,Tue Jun 16 04:50:37 2020,Mon Jun 15 23:25:56 2020,Tue Jun 16 05:47:19 2020,Mon Jun 15 00:12:41 2020,Tue Jun 16 06:28:36 2020,Mon Jun 15 01:47:55 2020,Tue Jun 16 07:13:24 2020,Thu Jun 11 16:55:46 2020,Mon Jun 15 03:27:30 2020,Mon Jun 15 04:28:36 2020,Mon Aug 21 01:40:16 2017,Mon Jun 15 00:11:00 2020,Mon Jun 15 05:17:44 2020,Sat May 23 06:05:25 2020,Sun Jun 14 03:00:20 2020,Mon Jun 15 23:41:05 2020,Sun Jun 14 05:00:00 2020,Sun Jun 14 01:24:15 2020,Sun Jun 14 02:28:35 2020,Mon Jun 15 05:00:02 2020,Fri Jun 12 00:18:34 2020,Sun Jun 14 00:31:11 2020,Wed Sep 12 12:57:25 2018,Mon Oct 21 14:05:02 2019,Wed Jan 29 17:00:11 2020,Wed Jan 29 17:01:44 2020,Thu Aug 01 10:50:47 2019,Tue Aug 20 09:31:08 2019,Wed Jun 17 01:04:27 2020,Wed Jun 17 01:39:39 2020,Wed Jun 17 00:59:24 2020,Wed Jun 17 00:30:44 2020,Wed Jun 17 00:16:11 2020,Wed Jun 17 00:14:26 2020,Wed Jun 17 01:18:33 2020,Wed Jun 17 00:58:36 2020,Wed Jun 17 01:03:17 2020,Wed Jun 17 00:46:27 2020,Wed Jun 17 00:28:01 2020,Wed Jun 17 00:18:39 2020,Wed Jun 17 02:57:09 2020
```

And I would like to transform those strings to datetime format, and I'm trying that using this:

```
dates_list = [dt.datetime.strptime(date, '"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"').date() for date in fechalist]
```

But it is returning me this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "netappdates.py", line 44, in <module>
    dates_list = [dt.datetime.strptime(date, '"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"').date() for date in fechalist]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 332, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Mon Jun 15 16:52:18 2020' does not match format '"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"'
```

I have tried to do the same format with datetime.now, as you can see below:

```
now = datetime.now()
print (now.strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"))
```

And it is returning me this date and time:

```
Wed Jun 17 09:30:43 2020
```

Just the same I want!

But I do not really get why is that format not working on my list!

Some ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The issue is extra quotes around format string: `'`.

Comment: Hello @Asocia as far as I can see, my string does not contain `'`

Comment: qutoes in this `'"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"'`. you can use either single quotes or double quotes. as per this format it's looking for date string with quoutes around it

Comment: @jmgalan I think you wrote that format to match `"` around your date strings but it is just a sign that tells Python it's a string. These are all same: `'s'` == `"s"` == `'''s'''` ... So you don't really need to consider that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Asocia said in his comment.
Your code

```
dt.datetime.strptime(date, '"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"')
```

Should be changed to

```
dt.datetime.strptime(date, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
```

By the way. I write this answer to suggest you another way.

First, install dateutil

Then, just run

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
parsed_list = [parse(date) for date in fecha_list]
```